# When I try to vote to close this question as a duplicate, the site tells me it doesn't have an upvoted answer, but it does. Is this a bug?

Tags: support, bug, questions, exact-duplicates, vote-to-close

See these two questions:

1. [whenever I start my windows laptop, after laptop is opened terminal is automatically opened and inside terminal its written -](https://superuser.com/questions/1733699/whenever-i-start-my-windows-laptop-after-laptop-is-opened-terminal-is-automatic), and
2. [On windows startup terminal opens automatically and showing file not found error](https://superuser.com/questions/1733771/on-windows-startup-terminal-opens-automatically-and-showing-file-not-found-error)

When I try to flag #2 as a duplicate, the site tells me there is no upvote on #1. But there is upvote (and downvote). Is this a bug, or odd sense of humor of developers/architects?

The exact message is:

> This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer

Comment: The net score is zero. Anyways you close the newer question as a dupe of the older. I've now done that.

Comment: @DavidPostill, I suspect that. But developers need to get the variable for upvotes. Or change the message.

Comment: @RomeoNinov - Bug reports like this belong on meta stack exchange